# Managing an event depending on date, XCODE

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5

I have a question (I have just a few months working on iOS and Objective-C)

In my app, I turn on a candle(png image array), but this candle has to remain ON for three days, the first day complete, the second one in the middle, and the third one completely melted.

I don't have idea how to do this... any help?

Answer (score 2):

You can just store the date the candle was lit in [`NSUserDefaults`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and when the app is started update the graphic based on that.

There is a really good WWDC video on date math, too.

You can also have a look at the NSCalendar https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html

docs.  and the all-important nsdatecomponents doc:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSDateComponents